# How to add fontawasome icon as a layer in geotools using javafx (Desktop App)?

Tags: javafx, geotools

I have been using java 17 and I'm unable to add icons into the map as a layer. please help me.

```
void drawTarget(double x, double y) {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("MyFeatureType");
        builder.setCRS( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84 ); // set crs
        builder.add("location", LineString.class); // add geometry
        // build the type
        SimpleFeatureType TYPE = builder.buildFeatureType();
        // create features using the type defined
        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
//        GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
//        Coordinate[] coords  =
//                new Coordinate[] {new Coordinate(79,25.00), new Coordinate(x, y)};
//        line = geometryFactory.createLineString(coords);
//        ln = new javafx.scene.shape.Line();
        FontAwesomeIcon faico = new FontAwesomeIcon();
        faico.setIconName("FIGHTER_JET");
        faico.setX(76);
        faico.setY(25);
        faico.setVisible(true);
//        TranslateTransition trans = new TranslateTransition();
//        trans.setNode(faico);
        featureBuilder.add(faico);
        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("FeaturePoint");
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("external", TYPE);
        featureCollection.add(feature); // Add feature 1, 2, 3, etc
        Style style5 = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.YELLOW, 2f);
        Layer layer5 = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style5);
        map.addLayer(layer5);
//        mapFrame.getMapPane().repaint();
    }
```

I want to add a font-awesome icon to the map

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: please show us some code to help us see what you are trying to do, and give us a clue about what is not working

Comment: please check ..

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code is attempting to use an `Icon` as a `Geometry` in your feature. I'm guessing that's what isn't working since you don't say.

If you want to use an `Icon` to display the location of a `Feature` then you will need two things.

1. A valid geometry in your feature, probably a point (since an Icon is normally a point)
2. A valid `Style` to be used by the `Renderer` to draw your feature(s) on the map. Currently, you are asking for the line in your feature to be drawn using a yellow line (`style5 = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.YELLOW, 2f);`)

I can't really help with step 1, since I don't know where your fighter jet currently is.

For step 2 I suggest you look at the [SLD resources](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/index.html) to give you some clues of how the styling system works before going on the [manual](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html) to see how GeoTools implements that.

Since you are trying to add an `Icon` I suggest you'd need something like:

```
    List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
    symbols.add(sf.externalGraphic(svg, "svg", null)); // svg preferred
    symbols.add(sf.externalGraphic(png, "png", null)); // png preferred
    symbols.add(sf.mark(ff.literal("circle"), fill, stroke)); // simple circle backup plan

    Expression opacity = null; // use default
    Expression size = ff.literal(10);
    Expression rotation = null; // use default
    AnchorPoint anchor = null; // use default
    Displacement displacement = null; // use default

    // define a point symbolizer of a small circle
    Graphic city = sf.graphic(symbols, opacity, size, rotation, anchor, displacement);
    PointSymbolizer pointSymbolizer =
            sf.pointSymbolizer("point", ff.property("the_geom"), null, null, city);

    rule1.symbolizers().add(pointSymbolizer);

    featureTypeStyle.rules().add(rule1);
```

But that assumes that you can convert your `FontAwesomeIcon` into a static representation that the renderer can draw (png, svg). If it doesn't work like that (I don't use JavaFX) then you may need to [add a new `MarkFactory` to handle them](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/icon.html).